# AttributeError: ' ' object has no attribute 'tk'?

Tags: tkinter, ttk

The point of this is to have one window that will obtain a zipcode from the user and save it. When the zipcode is saved it will open a new window that use the zipcode to display various weather information.

```
class EntryW(tk.Frame):
    def __init__( self, master ):
      self.master = master
      self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)     
      self.master.title("Weather by Josh")    

      self.label =  Label(self, text = "Enter Zipcode")
      self.label.pack(side = LEFT)
      global zipcodeEntryVar
      zipcodeEntryVar = tk.StringVar()

      self.entry = Entry(self,textvariable=zipcodeEntryVar)
      self.entry.pack(side = RIGHT)

      self.button1 = Button( self, text = "Submit", 
                           command +self.new_window )
      self.button1.pack(side = BOTTOM )
      self.frame.pack()

   def new_window(self):

     self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
     self.app = WeatherApp(self.newWindow)

class WeatherApp(tk.Frame):     
      def __init__(self, master):

         self.master = master
         self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
         self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Quit', 
                                    width = 25, command = self.close_windows)
         self.quitButton.pack()
         self.frame.pack()

      def close_windows(self):
         self.master.destroy()

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = EntryW(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Post the entire error output.

Comment: How do you import Tkinter? It seems like you're both doing `From Tkinter import *` since you use `Label(...)` and `Entry(...)` and `import Tkinter as tk` since you use `tk.Frame` and `tk.Button`. Stick to only one (preferably `import Tkinter as tk` to avoid namespace pollution and have a clear view on which classes are from Tkinter).